# Why is knex.js allowing to insert data whose type is different from its migration?

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I've been working with knex.js during the last days and I noticed that even though I specified some columns' types I can insert whatever type I want to.

For example, I have this table:

```
 exports.up = function (knex) {
  return knex.schema
    .createTable('users', function (table) {
      table.increments('id').primary();
      table.string('login', 255).notNullable();
      table.string('password', 255).notNullable();
      table.string('user_type', 255);
```

Even though I have string being the type for login, password and usertype, I can insert integers and no error will be thrown. Wasn't it supposed to throw an error on that?

Comment: Are your integers maybe converted to strings when you submit the login form? With JS .value they are.

Comment: no! that's not what is happening because the same issue happens when I try to send date through insomnia or postman! I'm sending the correct data types but for some reason it doesn't throw any errors (as I was expecting).

ps: one thing to note is that I'm using sqlite3 for not sure if that might be tha cause

Answer (score 1):

It is database driver dependent functionality. Knex really doesn't care what parameters you pass to query, it does not know any information about the schema that you have created.

So when you are giving dates or numbers to DB driver that is the part, which may or may not convert type for example from integer to string.

Since databases actually does not work with javascript types, the DB driver always needs to do some type of conversion from values JS representation to DB representation. So some automatic type conversions are expected.